# How to get the currently playing song (on the device) title in Swift?

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, wkwebview

I'm currently coding an app which displays a livestream embedded with an iframe loaded with WKWebView (loadHTMLString).

I want to show a "Loading" icon and label whenever the livestream is loading (or even buffering but not a big deal if I can't check if buffering).

Solutions I found:

1) Trying to listen for a media to be played with Javascript which then will send a message to the Swift code and put the "Loading" label in front.

Problem: It will be difficult to listen for a media to be played due to same-site policy (I can't access the body of an iframe downloaded from another source) and as I looked on loads of sites it seems to be difficult to send a message to Swift (I'm new to Swift).

2) Trying to look at the title of the song playing on the device (the title that is shown on the Control Center) because I noticed that whenever a livestream is being played in my app it would appear in the Control Center with the name of the site hosting the livestream.

I tried to look at multiple things but couldn't find one actually working.

3) Trying to look if something is being played with `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate]` (and an infinite loop with timer which might not be the greatest solution)
Or something like that.

But it seems like it always throws me `nil`

As said before, I'm new to Swift (started like 2 days ago) and don't really understand lots of things but if someone could explain to me how I could solve my problem (if there is one) I would be super grateful!

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmusicplayercontroller/1624245-nowplayingitem

Comment: @Wyetro But will it show me the currently playing title as shown in the Control Center or will it just give me a certain playback I should have added before (like with AVPlayer)??? (Because I do not manually load and play the media: the iframe launches itself in autoplay)

Comment: @Wyetro Also it would be nice if you could show me how to use this var (like how to get to the point where I get the infos because I don’t really know how to use variables from frameworks) (maybe in an answer to this question)